# Problem on getting date for search and the date inputted is not correct that dump() has shown in POSTMAN

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem about searching projects in range from `$startDate` and `$endDate`. When I input in POSTMAN 
`localhost:8000/api/getprojectbydate?startDate=2019-02-03&endDate=2019-07-04`
, I recieved the dump_data result is

```
Expression {#296
  #value: "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `startDate` BETWEEN ' + 2019-03-25 00:00:00 + ' AND ' + 2019-06-21 00:00:00 + '"
}
```

Somehow the date 2019-02-03 and 2019-07-04 is not shown correctly in the query. This is in my HomeController when doing the search function

```
public function getProjectByDate() {

        $startDate = Carbon::parse(request('startDate'));
        $endDate = Carbon::parse(request('endDate'));

            $project = DB::RAW("SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `startDate` BETWEEN ' + $startDate + ' AND ' + $endDate + '");

            dd($project);

        return array($project);
    }
```

Can anyone help for this issue getting value of parameter is wrong. Thanks

Comment: what is format of yoru posting data? is it yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-dd-mm ?

Comment: it is Y-m-d. But in the dd($project) it shown this
#value: "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `startDate` BETWEEN ' + 2019-03-25 00:00:00 + ' AND ' + 2019-06-21 00:00:00 + '"
But my input is 2019-02-03 and 2019-07-04

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: can you print $startDate and $endDate before sql query and show result??

Comment: okay hold on 
result of dump_data is Carbon @1553472000 {#293
  date: 2019-03-25 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not use raw query statements in this way as it is a security issue since it opens you up to query injection.

The reason you're getting the date in the format that you are is because `Carbon::parse()` will return a `Carbon` instance and when this is treated as a string (i.e. concatenated in your query) it will be converted to the format `Y-m-d H:i:s` by the `__toString()` method.

I would suggest using the [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-wherebetween) with the query builder and also `startOrDay()` and `endOfDay()` methods that come with `Carbon`.

```
public function getProjectByDate()
{
    $startDate = Carbon::parse(request('startDate'))->startOfDay();
    $endDate = Carbon::parse(request('endDate'))->endOfDay();

    $project = DB::table('projects')
        ->whereBetween('startDate', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->get();

    dd($project);

    return [$project];
}
```

---

If you only want/need the dates to contain the date and not the time then you can use the `format()` method instead:

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse(request('startDate'))->format('Y-m-d');
$endDate = Carbon::parse(request('endDate'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: it is weird that when i dump($startDate) and dump($endDate) it returns the wrong date 
Result return startDate = "2019-03-25" and endDate = "2019-06-21"
but correct date should be: startDate = "2019-02-03" and endDate = "2019-07-04"

Comment: This is really weird as I've just tried that and get the right results. Please can you just double check that the right value are showing up to begin with `dd(
        request('startDate'), Carbon::parse(request('startDate')),
        request('endDate'), Carbon::parse(request('endDate'))
    );`. This way we can see if it's an issue with `Carbon` or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a syntax error in your SQL query

Replace function:-

```
public function getProjectByDate() {

  $startDate = Carbon::parse(request('startDate'));
  $endDate = Carbon::parse(request('endDate'));

  $project = DB::RAW("SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `startDate` BETWEEN ' + 
  $startDate + ' AND ' + $endDate + '");

  dd($project);

  return array($project);
}
```

By

```
public function getProjectByDate() {

  $startDate = Carbon::parse(request('startDate'));
  $endDate = Carbon::parse(request('endDate'));
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `startDate` BETWEEN '".$startDate."' AND '".$endDate."'";

  $project = DB::RAW($sqlQuery);

  dd($project);

  return array($project);
}
```

Note : Start date should be like 2019-02-21 00:00:00 and EndDate should be 2019-02-21 23:59:59 if you are using the datetime datatype.

Comment: 1 thing weird it get the server time, it does not received the input from keyboard

Comment: @HuyNguyen can you post the table data and structure screenshot.

Comment: https://imgur.com/8bEJriv 

This is my table projects structure, and this is data inside projects table:
https://imgur.com/XfLfyjz

Comment: This one shows the POSTMAN testing the query and dd() data 
https://imgur.com/o65HgUl

Comment: @HuyNguyen you need to append 00:00:00 to date for example 
startDate 2019-02-21 00:00:00 AND endDate 2019-02-21 00:00:00 in sql query

Comment: Execute the following query in PHPmyadmin and show me the result

SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `startDate` BETWEEN '2019-02-20 00:00:00' AND '2019-06-22 00:00:00'

Comment: This is the result of the query that i received in phpmyAdmin
https://imgur.com/La1M5e8

Comment: This is the query which you need to use I think:-


SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `startDate` >= '2019-02-21 00:00:00' AND `endDate`  <= '2019-06-21 00:00:00'

Comment: i am a little bit confuse about this. https://imgur.com/28L2fLE
The startDate and endDate that i input (2019-01-01 as startDate, 2019-07-07 as endDate) it should be return the same date. 

But the green box that i dump it gets different date (startDate shows 2019-03-25 and endDate shows 2019-06-21) This is the point getting wrong datetime.

Comment: something is wrong with  the server date configuration, if you put the static SQL in your function as i supplied the query, it should work

Comment: hmmmmm cause i meet this one so weird. The time is correct, nothing wrong but when i use dd() i dont know that 2 datetime is from where. I think i will check again for server configuration